Why is "Skip To Main Content" suddenly appearing in my browsers?
I had been running the Brave browser for over 1 year.
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Suddenly a few weeks ago I started seeing the "Skip To Main Content" item popping up on numerous web pages.
I thought it was Brave.
Switched To MS Edge - Still Happens
Last week I switched MS Edge browser exclusively.  Now I'm seeing the Skip To Main Content feature in there too.   Why?
What I've Tried

Changing Browsers
Checking Accessibility settings in Ubuntu
Tried to get steps to recreate.  This "feature" is very difficult to get to repeat. It happens intermittently.  Plus not all sites implement the HTML for it.
Turned off all accessibilty features -- only 1 (Enable Animations) was turned on (shown in next snapshot).  I turned it off  but I still see the "Skip To Main Content"


A Possible Way to Recreate The Skip To Main Content feature
This "feature" occurs when you've

scrolled a bit down a page

switch to another tab

return to the original page that you scrolled down a bit on.

only occurs if the target web site has the "skip to main content" HTML included.


UPDATE - Additional Info On Recreating
It is quite likely that this feature occurs when a "sleeping" tab gets clicked on again. (All of the above has to be true also, but it may only occur when awakening a "sleeping" tab.  I recently saw the "feature" occur twice like that.
This Functionality Should Be Used In Specific Cases
This functionality should be on for Screen-readers and/or when only a Keyboard is attached.  That is not the case for me. I don't use a screen-reader and I have two mice and a keyboard connected to my computer.
Here are all the images I have showing that this feature intermittently pops up.
GitHub

WAll Street Journal

Google Drive

O'Reilly Tech Books web site

StackOverflow

Microsoft Dev Docs


That's not an Ubuntu change, that's components all on the sites themselves.  Especially if Brave and Edge (both NOT produced by Ubuntu) have that change.  I'm not sure if there's anything really other than the sites themselves that're doing this since those buttons all have different formats, etc. and there's a lot of rules and laws about accessibility that might enforce such a button.  FYI though, bug reporting is NOT done through Ask Ubuntu

@ThomasWard Thanks for the info.  I understand it's an accessibility item based on HTML and that would be within the purview of Browsers.  It is just very odd that suddenly I'm seeing this feature running Ubuntu but I've spoke with a few dozen people who normally run windows and none of them have ever seen this feature.  I just can't figure out why it started popping up in the past 2-3 weeks.  Wasn't sure if maybe it was related to an accessibility setting on Ubuntu itself.

I asked Copilot the question and here is what it told me:

My Question About Copilot's Answer
Well, then, why isn't everyone reporting that they are seeing this feature?  I can't find anyone else who has ever seen it.

This doesn't really answer your question.  This also isn't an Ubuntu specific feature, but remember that when things are 'well desired' by people companies and sites tend to add those accessibility features, or where they're mandated by law.  This is more a "general accessibility" thing not an ubuntu specific thing.  (FYI also this is NOT a discussion forum so this question you ask in your answer is not an answer and is slated to be deleted as a non-answer)
